# Get list of pdf files in folder

Tags: python

I want get a list of files name of all pdf files in folder I have my python script.

Now I have this code:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:

e = (len(files) - 1)
```

The problem are this code  found  all files in folder(include .py) so I "fix"  if my script is the last file on the folder (zzzz.py) and later  I subtract the last file of the list that are my script.py.

I try many codes for only find .pdf but this the more near I am.

Comment: Add this test  `and f.lower().endswith('.pdf')` in your `files list`

Answer (score 24):

Use the `glob` module:

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("*.pdf")
>>> ['308301003.pdf', 'Databricks-how-to-data-import.pdf', 'emr-dg.pdf', 'gfs-sosp2003.pdf']
```

Answer (score 21):

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) on the directory directly to find all your  pdf files:

```
from os import path
from glob import glob  
def find_ext(dr, ext):
    return glob(path.join(dr,"*.{}".format(ext)))
```

Demo:

```
In [2]: find_ext(".","py")
Out[2]: 
['./server.py',
 './new.py',
 './ffmpeg_split.py',
 './clean_download.py',
 './bad_script.py',
 './test.py',
 './settings.py']
```

If you want the option of ignoring case:

```
from os import path
from glob import glob
def find_ext(dr, ext, ig_case=False):
    if ig_case:
        ext =  "".join(["[{}]".format(
                ch + ch.swapcase())) for ch in ext])
    return glob(path.join(dr, "*." + ext))
```

Demo:

```
In [4]: find_ext(".","py",True)
Out[4]: 
['./server.py',
 './new.py',
 './ffmpeg_split.py',
 './clean_download.py',
 './bad_script.py',
 './test.py',
 './settings.py',
 './test.PY']
```

Comment: I believe you have one extra closing parenthesis after ch.swapcase on line 6 of your 2nd example. This is really great, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `endswith`:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith('.pdf')]
```

Comment: Haven't downvoted, but there are better tools for the job as seen in other answers, e.g. glob or fnmatch.

Answer (score 9):

### Python 3.4 and later: Use pathlib

Since Python 3.4 [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) should be used as it makes such tasks a lot simpler:

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = "."  # take the current directory as root

for path in Path(root).glob("**/*.pdf"):
    print(path)
```

gives:

```
.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/images/filesave.pdf
Downloads/2023-0310. Martin Thoma (1).pdf
```

So it goes recursively in other directories, including hidden ones. But it does NOT find `foo.PDF` - it is case-sensitive.

If you need it to be case insensitive:

```py
for path in Path(root).rglob('*'):  # iterate over all
    if path.suffix.lower() == ".pdf":  # check if the path pattern matches
        print(path)
```

### Older than Python 3.4: Use os

To get all PDF files recursively:

```
import os

all_files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".pdf")]:
        all_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```

Answer (score 8):

You simply need to filter the names of files, looking for the ones that end with ".pdf", right?

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
files = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(('.pdf','.PDF')), files)
```

Now, your `files` contains only the names of files ending with .pdf or .PDF :)

Comment: I use your code because is the more easy to understand for me but I want say thanks to everyone. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the following,

```
files = filter(
    lambda f: os.path.isfile(f) and f.lower().endswith(".pdf"),
    os.listdir(".")
)
file_list = list(files)
```

Or, in one line:

```
list(filter(lambda f: os.path.isfile(f) and f.lower().endswith(".md"), os.listdir(".")))
```

You may, or not, convert the filtered object to list using `list()` function.